# set key array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a CSV file im getting data from in an array im now trying to sort the array to display the content on the page. The csv comes as so

```
  image,price,product_id,link,description,title
  img.png,12.00,1000,www.site.com,some text,title text
  img.png,10.00,1001,www.site.com,some text,title text
  img2.png,10.00,1002,www.site.com,some text,title text
```

So far i have managed to group the first array by its image. What i cant work out how to do is group the prices in the group of images.

To start i had this

```
$result = array();
while (!gzeof($zd)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($zd, 1000, ","); //get csv data line by line
    $key  = array_shift($data); //set image as array key
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = array();
    }
    $result[$key][] = $data;
}
```

To display the data i did this

```
foreach ($result as $image => $entries) {
    $src = $image;
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($src); //test img url
    //tidy text for display
    $work       = substr($image, strrpos($image, '/') + 1);
    $work2      = explode(".", $work);
    $phone_name = $work2[0];
    $phone_name = str_replace("-", " ", $phone_name);
    $phone_name = str_replace("_", " ", $phone_name);
?>
    <table><tr><td width="30%" valign="top"><?php
    echo '<h4>' . $phone_name . '</h4>';
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"/><br> ' . "\n";
?> 
    </td><td><ul class="f_nav list-unstyled">    
    <?php
    ///display prices for each image
    foreach ($entries as $i => $entry) {
        $id = "{$entry[0]}\n";
?> 
<?php
        echo ' <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs active" role="button" title="';
        echo "{$entry[5]}\n";
        echo '">&pound';
        echo "{$entry[4]}\n";
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
?>  
 <?php
    }
?>
    </ul>
<?php
    echo "</td></tr></table><BR><BR>\n";
}
?>         
</td></tr></table>
```

This is great i got all the images grouped so only 1 displays with all the prices next to the item in a list. What i would like to do is display the prices next to each image in order low to high.

So i tried this

```
$result = array();
while (!gzeof($zd)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($zd, 1000, ",");
    $key  = array_shift($data);
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = array();
    }
    $result[$key][] = $data;
    $keyprice       = array_shift($data);
    if (!isset($results[$key][$keyprice])) {
        $results[$key][$keyprice] = array();
    }
    $results[$key][$keyprice][] = $data;
}
```

So my question is how do i arrange the prices in order?

Sorry if my question is stupid or not properly formatted. Im happy to explain more in details if needed. Im only human after all...

Comment: Argh, it hurts my eyes. The indentation is awful.

Comment: Hope my edits help you @Cthulhu :) @ OP In the future please can you indent your code to help readability. We don't want to reformat your code to help you solve a problem. (A good site to use is http://beta.phpformatter.com/ but most, if not all, IDEs have a formatting tool in it. It will also help your development if you adopt a good indentation technique)

Comment: @OP: If i get you right, you want to get your array sorted by the price and then display it. If so, you would want to take a look on this comment on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#99419) about sorting arrays by a specific key.

Comment: Thank you hd and Eddi after reading up on the sort function i have got it all to work. All i needed was a nudge in the right direction. I will read up on code format hd and improve my own wok thanks